# Which version of Python required to install IronPython in .net application

Tags: python, .net, python-2.7, python-3.x, ironpython

I installed IronPython 2.7.7 from nuget to my console application. I already have Python36 in my system.

My code

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        string dir = @"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\";
        paths.Add(dir);
        string dir2 = @"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\";
        paths.Add(dir2);
        engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
        dynamic test = ipy.UseFile(@"C:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Test1.py");
        test.Simple();
```

Code in Test.py

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
print 'train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
classifier.show_most_informative_features()
```

Its showing an exception like

```
No module named nltk.classify.util
```

What is missing here?

Comment: See their [website](http://ironpython.net/download/) for more informations. IronPython is compatible with `Python 2.7`.

Comment: And you have to install `nltk` with: `sudo pip install -U nltk` with `Python 2.7 up to 3.4 or 3.5`. See [here](http://www.nltk.org/install.html).

Comment: I already installed nltk and my site-packages contains nltk\classify\util.py

Comment: You can't mix Python 3.6 with Ironpython - 2 different runtimes!

Comment: @denfromufa Then how do I solve that issue if I am using IronPython only

Comment: `ironpython` has its own `pip` installer for packages from PyPI. If it does not work with `NLTK`, then try http://www.python4.net

Comment: @denfromufa how do I use the pip for ironpython in my .net application? Can you pls give me a brief idea.